# Salesforce redirects the knowledge article URL in a Napiili Community to another version with 301 Status Code

Tags: knowledge, redirect, napili, httpresponse, language

I am facing a strange behaviour in a Community tailored with Napiili Template. The technical details of the community are:

- I have enabled 2 languages for my Community: English(UK)(knowledge default language) and Italian
- I have enabled Knowledge Articles for my Org and I have created an Article Type
- I have created a custom Lightning component that in an article detail page, on the right, shows 2 links for the available versions of the article in one of the 2 languages mentioned before.

  **Test Case:**
- I have created 2 Articles, with two versions each, in English UK and Italian.
- For one of them I am able to navigate, and switch between two versions without any problem.
- *For another one, I am not able to access the italian version.*
- I cannot see any difference between these 2 example articles in data that they have or any other property.

  What I have noticed is that after the link is clicked, Salesforce responds with the status code 301(**Moved Premanently**) for the first request for the article in Italian, and then automatically redirects me to the version in English UK.

What I am interested to know now is why Salesforce arbitrarily performs this redirection of the URL? What does imply the status **Moved Permanently** for the first request?

Comment: Do you have a site Redirect Rule set up? Setup -> Site -> (Site Name) -> URL Redirects?

Comment: Nope, none of that configured.

Comment: Getting same error!!....@Endrit ...did you able to fix it?

Comment: Nope Ayub. After a session with someone from Salesforce Support(who was not a technical figure) that confirmed us that this is the way platform behaves, so we went in a full custom approach, which means, that now we have created a custom Article page, which gives us the freedom to show the articles, as we want without this restrictions.